# PowerShell Object Count

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm using VMware PowerCLI to query for datastores that have a certain amount of freespace.  The query could come back with nothing, just one, or more than one.  I feel like there's got to be an easier way to check if it's one or more than one.

```
$ds = get-datastore | where {$_.FreeSapceGB -gt 50} | Sort-Object FreeSpaceGB -descending
```

I know to check if I get results with this

```
if ($ds)
```

I know this will check if there's more than one

```
if ($ds.Count)
```

If there is more than one, I want to use the one with the most freespace so I use the first one

```
$ds[0]
```

But if there is only one, $ds[0] does not work and I have to use just $ds, which makes for too much duplicate coding.

I know I can limit my results with

```
| Select -first 1
```

But without limiting the results is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$ds = @(get-datastore | where {$_.FreeSapceGB -gt 50} | Sort-Object FreeSpaceGB -descending)
```

Then you should always be able to use $ds[0] as long as $ds.Count is greater than 0.

Comment: That takes care of it for me!  Thanks for such a quick response!